# Unable to check the rotation of items in AFrame

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, game-development

I'm trying to write a AFrame component that checks the rotation of an object. However, I am unsure of how to write the if statement to check.

I already know that the rotation attribute returns a the x,y,z in a set. However I am unsure of how to check it.

```
var rotation = document.querySelector('#checkItem').getAttribute('rotation');

if (rotation === {x: 0, y: 90, z: 00}) {
   document.querySelector('#key').setAttribute('visible');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS you have to check for the individual properties:

```
if (rotation.x === 0 && rotation.y === 90 && rotation.z === 0) { ... }
```